# What are the $fenv_access_off functions of libmath on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

Mountain Lion's implementation of libmath (located at /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib) has all the standard libmath functions, plus, for each of them, a `$fenv_access_off` variation. For instance, there's `acos`, and `acos$fenv_access_off`. (I do not have any other version of Mac OS installed available to check if it was the case before 10.8.)

What does `$fenv_access_off` mean?

I understand that I won't ever be calling directly any of these, but I'm still curious about them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [mailing list thread](http://lists.apple.com/archives/perfoptimization-dev/2008/Jun/msg00015.html) between some of Apple's engineers that contains a discussion about fenv_access_off. Stephen Canon, an Apple engineer, explains:

> C99 knows whether you are looking the IEEE flags / changing rounding
>   modes or not based on whether or not you've included fenv.h and done
>   #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS on or not, as required by standard. **So in principle, we could actually have two parallel math libraries, one
>   that spends time diligently setting flags and defending against
>   rounding mode changes and a faster one that does not. In practice,
>   this can be just implemented by having a separate set of symbols
>   decorated with $fenv_access_off for all the stuff in the math library**.

From the `man page` of `fenv`:

> The header  declares types, macros, and functions to provide
>   access to the floating-point environment, consisting of any
>   floating-point status flags and control modes supported by the
>   implementation.
>
> ...
>
> The FENV_ACCESS pragma provides a means to inform the compiler that
>   the program might access the floating-point environment to test status
>   flags or change the control modes.

Comment: I'm flattered, but Ian Ollmann actually wrote this explanation.

Answer (score 1):

These symbol variants with `$....` are there for backward compatibility, read [Symbol Variants Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Darwin/SymbolVariantsRelNotes/_index.html). This particular one, `$fenv_access_off` seems to be introduced for the compatibility with the new C standard. See [fenv.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/fenv.h.html) at the Open Group webpage.

Now, do `man fenv` on an OS X machine. The date of the man page is May 9 2011. I guess it was introduced with OS X Lion. (But I can't confirm, as I only have Mountain Lion machines.)