# What Rust construct uses nearbyint from libsystem_m?

Tags: performance, floating-point, rust

I've profiled my program with Valgrind and Callgrind and found that most of the time is spent in the `nearbyint$fenv_access_off` function.

I've found that it's a LLVM intrinsic, but which Rust language construct uses it? How can I avoid it?

[image: call map]

Comment: Could you please show your program so we have some context? Thank you.

Comment: More importantly, a screenshot of the trace is pretty useless. Look at the text form of the same data, and it will *tell you* what the containing item of `nearbyint` is (the small red rectangle). Follow it up the chain to see what is calling it.

Comment: All functions around it are `iter::_LT$impl$GT$next::next::h…yadayada` up until they become generic like `main()` (I suppose all my functions got inlined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reproduced it with:

```
fn main() {
    let data:Vec<_> = (0..999999).map(|x|{
        (x as f64).powf(2.2).round() as u8
    }).collect();
}
```

so it seems `as u8` is implemented using `nearbyint`.

It's the same speed as C `uchar = round(pow(i, 2.2))`, so I'll have to replace it with a good'ol lookup table…

Answer (score 2):

Doing a [search for `nearbyint`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/search?q=nearbyint&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) finds the related symbols `nearbyintf32` and `nearbyintf64`. These [are documented](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.4.0/src/libcore/intrinsics.rs#L484-L487) as returning the nearest integer to a floating point value. However, there appears to be no calls to that specific function.

`fenv_access_off` [appears to be an OS X specific aspect of the math library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13096137/155423).

The other thing in your trace is `round`. I can believe that `round` could use `nearbyint`. I also don't see any cases of `round` in the standard library that seem like they would occur in a tight loop.

Beyond this, anything is pure guessing.